# yii2 datapicker set endDate property from model

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2

I am using **yii2 datepicker** plugin and I had set the start date as today's date.

Now, I want to set `endDate` from my database. It varies as per record *cancel date*, which is different for each record:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'cancel_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'autoclose'=>true,
                                'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                                'startDate' => (string)date('d/m/Y'),
                                //'endDate' => '1/1/2017'
                            ],
                        ])->label(false); 
                    ?>
```

I need to set that `endDate` property to the value from my database.

Comment: Have you tried setting `'endDate' => $model->cancel_date`?

Comment: as the $model object is created using new keyword there is no value in  it . datepicker is in popup whitch shown on button click in my gridview.

Comment: In that case fetch the appropriate record from DB and set it to `endDate`. Something like `$tempModel = Model::find()->where(_<appropriate condition as per business logic>_)->one(); $endDt = $tempModel ->cancel_date;` and then finally `'endDate' => $endDt`. Without knowing more details it is difficult to be more specific than this.

Comment: thank you for the comment. but there are 1000's of records in my gridview and each records has button in it's row . on that button click i want endDate for that record only (endDate is different for each record) how would i take that dynamicaly and set it to the gridview endDate property

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the gridview and modal code, see what you have already done.

Answer (score 0):

You can render Your popup body with ajax. In controller action, responsible for rendering modal body, You can find corresponding model, and then pass it to popup view. In view just use `$model->cancel_date` as `end_date` param.